# get screen size in inches in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I have a page that I want to set the initial zoom a little lower on smaller screen sizes, the problem is that I can't get the screen size within javascript, I need to zoom out on screens between 13 and 14 inches but there is no logical way to get that from the pixel values

I have the same problem on mobile, on certain phones the page looks good but on others it doesn't, instead of rebuilding everything I just wanna zoom out

I know it might be bad practice but if there is a way to do it that's what I wanna do

Comment: @bZezzz — No, it doesn't. The size of the pixel depends on the size of the screen and the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by what bZezzz wrote, but with some code to retrieve actual screen dimensions. Also note that `screen.availHeight` and `screen.availWidth` return the screen size, and might not be that helpful if your page is being rendered on only a part of the screen.

```js
let hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(screen.availHeight**2 + screen.availWidth**2)
console.log(
  'pixels', hypotenuse,
  'inches', hypotenuse / 96 // Per spec, there are 96 pixels per inch
);
```

Comment: "96 pixels per inch" — No. That's an default value set on some systems for software which needs to convert between physical and pixel values. It's an obsolete approach that never did a good job of reflecting reality.

Comment: @Quentin, while I do agree this certainly isn't the right way to go about what OP wants to achieve (assuming an XY-problem here), 96 pixels is defined as one inch by the CSS standard. See [section 4.3.2 of the most recent version](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units), which defines a pixel as 3/4pt, in turn defined as 1/72th of an inch.

Comment: @CerebralFart that spec is for "printers" only.  For screens, it depends on the size of the screen, so just assuming there are 96 dots in an inch on a 20 inch monitor, and the exact same on a 13 inch monitor, is obviously not right